# SSIS SQL Server Destination Good or Bad?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Do people still recommend NOT using the SQL Server Destination? I know there have been questions about this in the past, but they seem to be from 4+ years ago. I have been timing OLEDB versus SQL Server Destination for ~5million+ records, the time savings are definitely enough where I need to consider it. The source/target databases and ssis packages are located on the same server.

Comment: Really? How do you have your OLEDB Destination configured?

Answer (score 4):

> The source/target databases and ssis packages are located on the same server.

Since you have above, you can use SQL Server destination. From [Data loading performance guide :](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070%28v=sql.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The SQL Server destination is the fastest way to bulk load data from an Integration Services data flow to SQL Server. This destination supports all the bulk load options of SQL Server – except ROWS_PER_BATCH.
>
> Be aware that this destination requires shared memory connections to SQL Server. This means that it can only be used when Integration Services is running on the same physical computer as SQL Server.

Internally, SQL Server destination uses `Bulk Insert` .. uses `Shared Memory` which is extremely fast (you can confirm running a trace to see what it is executing behind the hood).

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I understand the drawbacks, not as detailed errors and portability, but are there any others that I should be aware of?

Comment: @JasonB. nope, infact it is recommended to use SQL Server destination if  your ssis is running on the same machine (which you already have). Just make sure that you have [enough memory (max memory for sql server buffer pool) and OS memory (for OS, SSIS, etc)](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108273/8783)